# JMapViewer.jar Direct Download Link?

Tags: java

I need a direct link to download the JAR file of JMapViewer. The problem is that I found one link but all what is providing to me is a zipped folder containing text files(not binary files)!
The link I used is:

http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer/releases/1.03/

So please help I searched a lot and couldn't find a useful link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release directories contain a soure and a binary archive, at least the 1.04 version.

http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/viewer/jmapviewer/releases/1.04/JMapViewer-1.04.zip

The 1.03 is indeed broken.